# Origem dinâmica do dados do gráfico

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela no Excel, `Tab_Visitas`, que tem as visitas por dia do mês.

[image: http://prntscr.com/35o4aw]

O que queria fazer era um gráfico de linhas, mas só com a data seleccionada e a data anterior à seleccionada, tipo isto:

[image: exemplo]

A obtenção das datas já tenho:

```
DataSelecionada:= DATA($Q$2;CORRESP($P$2;Tab_Meses;0);1)
DataAnterior:= DATAM(DataSelecionada;-1)
```

Como coloco o gráfico a só apresentar os dados do mês indicado, bem como o anterior? (de preferência só com formulas)

Answer (score 2):

Na sua pergunta não está claro como você organizou os seus dados, mas eu entendi que o gráfico está em uma planilha (aba) separada da dos dados e por isso você pega a data de referência da célula Q2 (agora, depois da sua alteração mais recente, P2).

Enfim, uma possível solução possível é a seguinte:

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Row = 2 And Target.Column = 17 Then

        dCurDate = Target.Value
        dPrevDate = DateAdd("m", -1, Target.Value)

        Set oChart = ChartObjects(1)

        With Sheets("Visitas")
            Set oSearchRange = .Range("B4", .Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
            Set oCurResp = oSearchRange.Find(What:=dCurDate, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            Set oPrevResp = oSearchRange.Find(What:=dPrevDate, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not oCurResp Is Nothing And Not oPrevResp Is Nothing Then
                oChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(oPrevResp.Row, 2), .Cells(oCurResp.Row, 34)), PlotBy:=xlRows
            Else
                MsgBox "Intervalo de datas não encontrado!"
            End If
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Funciona da seguinte forma:

- A função captura o evento de alteração da planilha (`Worksheet_Change`) e verifica se a alteração ocorreu na célula da linha 2 coluna 17 (você mudou agora há pouco para a célula P2, mas antes estava na Q2 - foi o que eu usei no exemplo).
- Se essa célula foi alterada, o código faz uma busca nos dados da planilha (aba) "Visitas" (eu chamei assim aqui, mudei ai de acordo com o seu arquivo do Excel). O intervalo (range) da busca é a coluna B, onde estão as datas. Ele faz duas buscas: pela data atual e pela data anterior (desconta 1 mês da data atual, de forma similar a que você já fez no seu código).
- Se ele encontrar as duas datas, faz a alteração da fonte dos dados no gráfico (considerei que é o primeiro na planilha atual - onde você deve adicionar esse código!) indicando que os dados devem ser plotados na horizontal (estão na direção das linhas). Note que o intervalo (range) é definido pelas linhas encontradas nas duas buscas anteriores e nas colunas dos dias (2 a 34). Note também que nada mais é alterado no gráfico, apenas a origem dos dados. Os dados dos eixos assim como a formatação é mantido como estava antes.

Comment: não dá pra fazer sem recurso a VBA? só com formulas?

Comment: Hum... posso estar enganado, mas eu creio que não. Não é tanto pela busca (há funções de *lookup* que podem ser usadas diretamente nas células), mas pela atualização da propriedade `SourceData` do gráfico. Se você utilizar a interface gráfica para inserir uma fórmula verá que não existe uma categoria "gráfico".